# How to form two sql insert statements from the JSON array

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have got a JSON Array as shown below

```
[{
    "link_video": "123"
}, {
    "link_video": "456"
}]
```

By parsing i want to create two insert sql as

```
Insert into mytable values (123,456);
Insert into mytable values (456,123);.
```

I have started as shown below , could you please tell me how can i form two sql

```
public class Testeee {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, SQLException {

        String array = "[{\"link_video\":\"123\"},{\"link_video\":\"456\"}]";

        JSONArray array_jsn = new JSONArray(array);

        PreparedStatement PstmtdeleteforLinkVideos = null;
        Connection con;

        String sql = "Insert into mytable values (?,?)";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonoo",
                "root", "root");

        PstmtdeleteforLinkVideos = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        for (int i = 0; i < array_jsn.length(); i++) {
            String id = array_jsn.getJSONObject(i).getString("link_video");
            PstmtdeleteforLinkVideos.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(id));

            PstmtdeleteforLinkVideos.addBatch();

        }

        PstmtdeleteforLinkVideos.executeBatch();
    }

}
```

Comment: does it not work? if so where does it fail?

Comment: i am not able to insert the second value PstmtdeleteforLinkVideos.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(id));

Comment: what do you mean with "not able to insert"?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is expecting two values. But your code below is assigning only one value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_jsn.length(); i++) {
    String id = array_jsn.getJSONObject(i).getString("link_video");
    PstmtdeleteforLinkVideos.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(id));
    PstmtdeleteforLinkVideos.setInt(2,Integer.parseInt(id));
    PstmtdeleteforLinkVideos.addBatch();
}
```

you have to set parameter index 2 also.

Then it will work.